# How to solve this chart line example in PWBI or Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

Obs:

The final database has 40 countries, 5 regions and range 2008:2018. Here's a small example of the base to illustrate the problem in Pibx [file.pbix](https://prequest.websiteseguro.com/bi).

The idea consists in a dynamic chart, which will be update according to user interaction, as follow some examples:

When opening the dashboard, the first screen that the user would see would already be this one with all filters active/selected and show on the chart line the result of [Filter avg %YOY Region] between the period from 2008 to 2011 (due it is active) already starting the option {Avg National} enabled.
[image]

Now, suppose that the user clicks on the value {P1} in [Value by Country] to view the corresponding result of [Avg % YoY] on the chart and wants to compare this result with all years . The result of this selection would be:
[image]

Now, suppose that the user clicks on the value {P1} in [Value by Country] to view the corresponding result of [Avg % YoY] on the chart and wants to compare this result with all measures of [Filter avg %YOY Region]. The result of this selection would be:
[image]

Now, suppose that the user clicks on the value {P1} and {P2} in [Value by Country] to visualize the result of [Avg % YoY] of the respective filters on the chart line and wants to compare the results with the mean {Avg SE } in [Filter avg %YOY Region]. The result of this selection would be:
[image]

Applying the same logic to other possible ideas including the year filter.

Answer (score 0):

> How does Pwbí manage to do this wrong account? Mean (19.72 - 2.02) = 10.41?

In a measure each cell is recalculated.  So the measure for SE is not calculated by averaging the measure at the P2 and P3 grain.  If it did, then P2 and P3 would always be equally weighted, which isn't normally what you want.

Instead the measure is recalculated for the SE grain.

Comment: But I need it to calculate for SE and similar like CO and Other regions the following: AVERAGE(SUM(P1,P2)). In Excel and R, both return 8.85. In this example, by coincidence, as CO only has one Country linked in the example, to AVERAGE = P1. How to Return CO, SE, "n" the result of an AVERAGE(SUM(X1:n)) measure?

Comment: What does `AVERAGE(SUM(P1,P2))` mean.  Isn't that just `SUM(P1,P2)`?  Can you simplify your example down to the bare minimum and explain the desired logic?